# How to add Navigation Drawer to existing Android app with custom view pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer

Hi I have an existing application that uses custom view page extending `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`. Inside I have tabs navigation.

Now I need to add Navigation drawer to all activities. What's the best way to achieve that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found this tutorial helps a lot. Just in case someone is in the same boat, give it a try. I could make it work with my existing app. Cheers.

http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/